# Message error after grub menu

Tags: kubuntu, initramfs

When I start the laptop on which i installed only Kubuntu 20.04, the GRUB menu appears, after which on the black screen I receive the following message `initramfs unpacked failed etc.`

After this message, the login screen appears and the operating system starts with no error. All applications run very fast and without crashes.

Should I reinstall Kubuntu 20.04 or this error message shouldn't bother me?

Comment: I only sometimes get the grub menu and error message when i turn on the laptop.

Comment: This is perfectly normal! These errors popup for most people even me! Its best to ignore it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decoding error reported in `dmesg` is actually harmless and has no impact on the usability of the system. I searched the net and switching from `lz4` compression to `gzip` compression only means that it no longer displays the error but in addition the boot time increases.
In conclusion i expect the `kernel` to be updated to resolve this error message by Ubuntu developers in the near future.

Comment: I can add that this happens only if microcode is loaded by the OS. You can check it by `dmesg | grep microcode`. If the vendor provides BIOS with a new microcode, and you flash it, the message will disappear.